# I want to make a "message" like window in .CSS with .php and fetch from mysql. A new block each row

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, fetch

I want to make a "message" like window, i will add a picture of how it is - and i don't want it like that. I want it more like on an iPhone - with the green block surounding each message.

```
$sql="SELECT ordene FROM ordene";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
// Fetch one and one row
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{



//printf("%s<p><span>",$row[0],"</span><p>");
//printf ("%s",$row[0]);
  echo "<br>";
echo $row[0];


}
 // Free result set
 mysqli_free_result($result);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ckhh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a quick template for you to work on
https://jsfiddle.net/ymeq31rt/

Replacing the `<p>` with your messages output from php code, and don't forget that you need to give your elements the corresponding class so they will be styled. if my answer helped you please mark as answer.